# the file says it's there, but it's not really there at all

Tags: linux, perl, unix, filesystems

What condition could cause this?

1. a dentry for the file exists

   -e says the file is there

   cat says "No such file or directory"

```
opendir(my $dh, $tdir) or die "Could not open temp dir: $!";
for my $file (readdir($dh)) {
    print STDERR "checking file $tdir/$file\n";
    next unless -e "$tdir/$file";
    print STDERR "here's the file for $tdir/$file: ";
    print STDERR `cat $tdir/$file`;
    die "Not all files from hub '$hid' have been collected!: $tdir/$file";
}
```

Output:

```
checking file 
/tmp/test2~22363~0G0Tjv/22363~0~4~22380~0~1~Test2~Event~Note
here's the file for /tmp/test2~22363~0G0Tjv/22363~0~4~22380~0~1~Test2~Event~Note: 
cat: /tmp/test2~22363~0G0Tjv/22363~0~4~22380~0~1~Test2~Event~Note: No such file or directory
IPC Fatal Error: Not all files from hub '22363~0~4' have been collected!:
```

I realize that theoretically some other process or thread could be stepping on my file in between cycles, but this is Perl (single-threaded) and Test2/Test::Simple's test directory, which should be limited to being managed by the master process.

What's brought me here is that I've seen similar errors in other code we have:

```
if(-e $cachepath) {
    unlink $cachepath
        or Carp::carp("cannot unlink...
```

which throws "cannot unlink..."

also

```
$cache_mtime = (stat($cachepath))[_ST_MTIME];
....
if ($cache_mtime){
       open my($in), '<:raw', $cachepath
            or $self->_error("LoadError: Cannot open $cachepath for reading:
```

which throws that "LoadError: cannot open..." exception

Those are in cases which *also* should only have the one process operating on the directory, and that all makes me suspect there's something going on.

This is linux kernel, fully up-to-date with vendor patches.

Comment: Is it a broken symlink perhaps?

Comment: What do you see in the shell?  `ls -l`? `stat`?

Comment: @that other guy, Good guess, except `-e` returns false of a broken symlink.

Comment: Note that `unlink $cachepath` and `open my($in), '<:raw', $cachepath` can fail even if a file exists, so that whole bit about similar errors is meanlingless unless `$!` was `No such file or directory`.

Comment: According to you, `unlink` and `open` in the same process says the file doesn't exist, and `open` in an external process (`cat`) says the file doesn't exist. If it was just the last, I'd suspect a possibly-unprintable shell meta-character. But give that you are only getting this problem intermittently (right?), and that your own process says the file doesn't exist, I believe the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it really was child processes and race conditions. The newer code in Test::Simple doesn't work well with nested subtests. Anyway, thanks for allowing me to rule out some obscure filesystem thing that I didn't know about.